# iOS UIWebView popup blocker issue

Tags: ios, uiwebview

In iOS, the default behavior when I open my webpage is that after login it opens the next page in a new window. But now when I open it in iOS webview, it does not open the next page. I google about it, and the cause seems to be the popup blocker. So, is there any simple way to disable the popup blocker in the iOS webview?

Answer (score 0):

The webpage might have a redirection that you are not handling properly.

You may first want to use `webView:didFailNavigation:withError:` or `webView:didFailProvisionalNavigation:withError:` to get some reasons or clues. And you can try to debug `webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:decisionHandler:` to see whether you are allowing the navigation.

If the redirection somehow generates an `about:blank` page in the transition, you could try to use `UIWebViewDelegate`'s `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` and returns a `YES` if `request.URL.absoluteString` is indeed `about:blank`, for example:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if ([request.URL.absoluteString isEqualToString:@"about:blank"]) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

BTW, you also can try to use Safari to debug `webView`s in your simulator. For instance, try `document.location` in your inspector to see what actually is the URL when the page doesn't open.

Comment: Please provide some sample code or refer one sample project to implement the same ?