# How to disable popup blocker on webview?

Tags: ios, swift, webview

Hi I'm looking for a solution that disable popup blocker on webview (for facebook).
Already checked this solution [IOS UIwebview popup blocker issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37102931/ios-uiwebview-popup-blocker-issue)
 but not useful, 
How can I make the app allow that message to appear, so the use can hit ‘allow’ which will let the page load as it is supposed to?
please guide me through a proper solution.